# How collection properties are to be used with Blender

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I'm trying to get collection properties working. I have looked at examples at Blender documentation, but maybe the API has changed a bit, or I am just getting it totally wrong somehow.

This fairly simple snippet fails:

````
>>> cp=bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=bpy.props.FloatProperty)
>>> cp.add()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'```
````

printing out cp gives

```
(<built-in function CollectionProperty>, {'type': <built-in function FloatProperty>})
```

Meaning it is a tuple. How to add more entries? I understood that that was the purpose of CollectionProperty. According to documentation, a simple

```
cp.add()
```

should do it.

Comment: Looks like that for the code to work, the class needs to be part of bpy.props.Scene.

Comment: The API regarding collection property hasn't changed much (if at all) since 2.49.  Please refer to the example in the docs https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#collection-example  You define a property on a class, you add to an instance.

Comment: yes that example works, thanks